# Dealing with nIl? in UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, null

Ok, after solving the problem with "the self" now I'm struggling to understand why I cannot unwrap the results from my MysqlDB. The app connects, retrieve datas and then it might show them. The problem is that it cannot unwrapp. Here the code

**ViewController.swift**

```
import UIKit
 class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource,     UITableViewDelegate, HomeModelProtocol {

//downloadItems
func itemsDownloaded(items: NSArray) {
    feedItems = items
    self.listTable.reloadData()
}

//link tV
@IBOutlet weak var listTable: UITableView!
//Proprietà
var feedItems: NSArray = NSArray()
var selectList : ListModel = ListModel()



//tableView
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return feedItems.count
}

//viewDidLoad
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    //set delegates and initialize a homeModel
    self.listTable.delegate = self
    self.listTable.dataSource = self

    let homeModel = HomeModel ()
    homeModel.delegate = self
    homeModel.downloadItems()
}


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) ->UITableViewCell {
    let cellIdentifier : String = "BasicCell"
    let myCell: UITableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdentifier)!

    //recupero food
    let item : ListModel = feedItems[indexPath.row] as! ListModel

    //reference alla label
    myCell.textLabel!.text = item.description

    return myCell
}}
```

**ListModel.swift**

```
import Foundation
class ListModel : NSObject {

//proprietà
var name: String?
var percentage: Int?
var other: String?
var id: Int?


override init(){
}

init(name: String, percentage: Int, other: String, id: Int){
    self.name = name
    self.percentage = percentage
    self.other = other
    self.id = id
}

//stampa oggetti
override var description: String{
    return "Name: \(name), Percentuale: \(String(describing: percentage)), Altro: \(other)"
}}
```

**HomeModel.swift**

```
import Foundation

protocol HomeModelProtocol: class {
    func itemsDownloaded(items: NSArray)
} 

class HomeModel: NSObject, URLSessionDataDelegate{
//proprietà
weak var delegate: HomeModelProtocol!
var data = Data()
let urlPath: String = "http://www.sake-house.net/webServices.php"

func downloadItems(){
    let url : URL = URL(string: urlPath)!
    let defaultSession = Foundation.URLSession(configuration: URLSessionConfiguration.default)
    let task = defaultSession.dataTask(with: url) {(data, response, error) in
        if error != nil{
            print("downloasd fallito")
        }else{
            print("Dati scaricati")
            parseJSON(data!)
        }
    }
    task.resume()
}} 
func parseJSON(_ data:Data){
var jsonResult = NSArray()

do{
    jsonResult = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.allowFragments) as! NSArray
} catch let error as NSError{
    print (error)
}

var jsonElement = NSDictionary()
let listFoods = NSMutableArray()

for i in 0..<jsonResult.count {
    jsonElement = jsonResult[i] as! NSDictionary

    let listF = ListModel()

    if let name = jsonElement["Name"] as? String, let percentage = jsonElement["Percentage"] as? Int, let other = jsonElement["other"] as? String, let id = jsonElement["id"] as? Int{
        listF.name = name
        listF.percentage = percentage
        listF.other = other
        listF.id = id
    }
    listFoods.add(listF)

    //check listFoods
    DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: { () -> Void in self.delegate.itemsDownload(items: listFoods)}) <--------HERE

}}//fine func parseJSON
```

The problem is on this row

```
let myCell: UITableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdentifier)!
```

> "Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"

In `ViewController.swift`. If I delete this line it works and show me **Name: nil**.

Answer (score 1):

This line crashes

```
 let myCell: UITableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdentifier)!
```

as you need to register the cell for that tableView , you need to create a custom cell then use

```
let myCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdentifier) as! CellName
```

---

Register

```
tableView.register(CellName.self, forCellReuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier)
```

// or  for xib

```
tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "xibname", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: cellIdentifier)
```

---

```
class CellName:UITableViewCell {

   // outlets here 

}
```

Comment: Mmm...I cannot understand how to use it. I have to "tableView.register" and then let myCell? Xcode says that I'm trying to use an unsolved identifier "CellName"

Comment: create a class like above and xib then connect outlets and then register the xib

Comment: But then I Cannot use "listTable" (that is also the outlets) outside of the class

Comment: I solved this in someway. I was doing it in the wrong way. Also if I stil don't understand how to use CellName class and why put there the outlets. Now I can see "nil" in my app when showing data

Answer (score 0):

So, I have tried as Sh_Khan said. I think I'm missing something or I have done it wrong at all. Inside Viecontroller.swift

```
class CellName:UITableViewCell {

}
@IBOutlet weak var listTable: UITableView!
```

and then

```
tableView.register(CellName.self, forCellReuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier)
let myCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdentifier) as! CellName
```

Now I can see something but as result I see "nil"

Comment: I solved this in someway. I was doing it in the wrong way. Also if I stil don't understand how to use CellName class and why put there the outlets. Now I can see "nil" in my app